# How to access external file from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to access values of another file from `application.properties`?

Let's say I have this `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypwd
```

Instead I would like to have two files

application.properties

```
external-file=\mysecondfile.properties  //external file from where to get the actual values
spring.datasource.url={url} //url from spring.datasource.url property in mysecondfile.properties 
spring.datasource.username={username} //username from spring.datasource.url property in mysecondfile.properties
spring.datasource.password={password}  //password from spring.datasource.url property in mysecondfile.properties
```

mysecondfile.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypwd
```

`mysecondfile.properties` could be of other format as well `(.txt, .xml, .yml...)`. The only requirement it's to be able to acess it's content like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.
Please note first that you have much more options. All details are mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files)

Answer to your question:
[Importing Additional Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.importing)

```
spring.application.name=myapp
spring.config.import=optional:file:./dev.properties
```

The imported properties will take precedence. The position of the import within the file doesn't matter.

I still suggest to check the documentation for completeness.